System.Threading.ThreadStateException in WinFrom .NET 6 on Clipboard.SetText()
I have a WinForm .Net 6 application in which I have a Dialog that creates another Dialog containing validation warnings, called WarningDialog.cs.
In that Dialog I have a button, which needs to copy a memo text into the Clipboard.
That button has the following OnClick method:
        /// <summary>
    /// Copy to clipboard
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender">sender</param>
    /// <param name="e">e</param>
    private void m_CopyToClipBoard_Click (Object sender, EventArgs e) {
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(m_Memo.Text)) {
            try {
                Thread thread = new Thread(() => {
                    // Check if Invoke is required (if we're not on the UI thread)
                    if (this.InvokeRequired) {
                        this.Invoke(new Action(() => Clipboard.SetText(m_Memo.Text)));
                    } else {
                        Clipboard.SetText(m_Memo.Text);
                    }
                });

                // Ensure the thread is set to STA mode
                thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
                thread.Start();

                // Update UI elements directly on the UI thread
                m_CopyToClipBoard.Visible = false;
                m_CopiedToClipboardLabel.Visible = true;
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                // Handle errors and ensure the UI remains responsive
                m_CopyToClipBoard.Visible = true;
                m_CopiedToClipboardLabel.Visible = false;
            }
        }
    }

However, I get the following exception on the line this.Invoke(new Action(() => Clipboard.SetText(m_Memo.Text)));:
System.Threading.ThreadStateException: 'Current thread must be set to single thread apartment (STA) mode before OLE calls can be made. Ensure that your Main function has STAThreadAttribute marked on it.'

I find this weird as I run the Thread as ApartmentState.STA.
I checked around for solutions, hence the Thread usage and invoke required check.
Also. my Program.cs has the [STAThread] attribute.
Is this an issue because it is a button in a Dialog, that is being triggered by another Dialog?

You don't need to invoke if you copy text first into variable. Related.

Clipboard.SetText is throwing the exception, not the m_Memo.Text. I already tried assigning m_Memo.Text to a variable first

Why do you start a thread here?  You start a thread to then execute it in the main thread. We can safely assume m_CopyToClipBoard_Click is running on the main thread. Why don't you simply call Clipboard.SetText without the Thread?

@Ralf, see related topic.

He said his main thread is an STAThread so shouldn't fall into that trap when he just not use an additional thread?

And thanks @Sinatr for the heads up I didn't know about that problem.

@Ralf Yet it is... Somehow? At least calling Clipboard.SetText() without the thread stuff causes the same exception.

If you call GetApartmentState() what does it tell you? The link @Sinatr provided showing th eproblem and a solution is from the Net Framework timeframe i'm pretty sure the complete ApartmentState stuff has changed since then.

@Ralf thread.GetApartmentState(); returns STA (I called it before thread.Start())

Remove any threading stuff, quite useless. If you actually have [STAThread] in the main entry point of your app, then show how / where these dependent dialogs are created and shown
